# Counting dates as numbers in python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

So I have this excel file that I loaded into my notebook (roughly 900,000 rows) and it has a column "Date" that I want to access. I access it and I am trying to count the number of dates, I want to have the number of dates say all 900,000 as 1, 2, 3... all the way to 900,000. Afterwards I want to be able to square that number to create another column to put in my dataframe.

'''

```
day = (df['Date'])

def da():
    for i in range(len(day)):
        print (i + 1)
```

'''

I end up getting an output of what I want but I can not square it nor do much else with it using a for loop. Is there a simpler way to do this? New to this so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an index column starting from 1, you don't even have to create the extra serie called `Day`:

```
df['squared_index'] = df.index**2
```

If it does not start with zero, you can subtract (or add) an offset, in this case we are summing 1:

```
df['squared_index'] = (df.index+1)**2
```

Anyway you can still utilize a serie as an auxiliar column:

```
df['squared_index'] = pd.Series(range(0,len(df))**2
```

We have used `**2`, but there are other ways to accomplish the same result:

```
df.index**2                 # regular python **2

np.square(df.index)         # numpy square

pd.Series(df.index).pow(2)  # pow function - here we have to use serie
                            # because it does not apply to indexes
```